# Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image returns unsecure product image url in custom CLI command

Tags: magento2, cli

I am using Magento's image helper class to try to get a product's image url in a CLI command:
`$this->image->init($product, 'product_page_main_image_default')->getUrl()`.

When I use this code in a block in a frontend page, it returns `https://...` but when used in a CLI command it instead returns `http://...`. I was having the same issues with the `Magento\Framework\UrlInterface` where getting the base url also returned the insecure version. I had to explicitly specific `$this->url->getBaseUrl(array('_secure' => true))` to get the secure version.

For the CLI command, I am setting the area code to `frontend` and I am also emulating the frontend store view `$this->emulator->startEnvironmentEmulation(1, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);` My admin has the correct Secure Base Url and Base Link Url in place.

I am wondering if I am doing something wrong or if anyone knowns a fix to get the secure product image url rather than doing a `str_replace` on the insecure url.

Edit: added relevant code snippet:

Where I am attempting to get secure product image url, using `Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory` and `Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image`:

```
$product = $this->productFactory->create()
                ->setId($id)
                ->setImage($imageLink);

$this->image->init($product, 'product_page_main_image_default')->getUrl();
```

Comment: Show the code which you done for custom command CLI?

Comment: added relevant code, entire command is very large

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$product = $this->productFactory->create()
                ->setId($id)
                ->setImage($imageLink);

$store = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();
$imageUrl = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work, it still returns an unsecure url

Comment: Have you check, into secure url you have enter proper URL from admin.

Comment: Urls are properly set in admin.